# my script for a bot stops working randomly after around 20 or so tries

Tags: python, pyautogui

so I'm trying to make a program that plays the sequence memory minigame on humanbenchmark.com, and it works really well for around 20 or so tries. seemingly randomly, the program will fail to loop and it will just not run anymore. basically the program checks 9 pixels on top of each square and sees if it turn white. if it does, it adds the index of that square : [ 1, 2, 3, to a string. after each level, the length of the
4, 5, 6,
7, 8, 9 ]
sequence you need to remember gets longer and the program keeps track of that too in the levels variable. I've done this to save memory, by storing it inside a string rather than an array, and looping through each character, and using a dictionary to convert the number in the string to a position. I've talked with chatgpt a little about this and the bot said it may be an issue with pyautogui and that it may be unstable, but i really just have no clue. I'm not even sure if its a memory problem i just need help.

i ran the program but it just failed to loop and stopped working after 18 - 24 or so loops.

my code is below:

```
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import win32api, win32con

orderedPositions = ""

pixels = { '1':(1140, 290),
           '2':(1270, 290),
           '3':(1400, 290),
           '4':(1140, 425),
           '5':(1270, 425),
           '6':(1400, 425),
           '7':(1140, 550),
           '8':(1270, 550),
           '9':(1400, 550), }

def click(mouseX, mouseY):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((mouseX, mouseY))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0)

level = 1
iterations = 0
def checkingLoop():
    while True:
        global level
        global iterations
        global orderedPositions
        while iterations < level:
            if pyautogui.pixel(1140, 290)[0] == 255: # pixel 1
                if iterations == level - 1:
                    orderedPositions += "1"
                    print("added 1")
                time.sleep(0.5)
                iterations += 1
                continue
            elif pyautogui.pixel(1270, 290)[0] == 255: # pixel 2
                if iterations == level - 1:
                    orderedPositions += "2"
                    print("added 2")
                time.sleep(0.5)
                iterations += 1
                continue
            elif pyautogui.pixel(1400, 290)[0] == 255: # pixel 3
                if iterations == level - 1:
                    orderedPositions += "3"
                    print("added 3")
                time.sleep(0.5)
                iterations += 1
                continue 
            elif pyautogui.pixel(1140, 425)[0] == 255: # pixel 4
                if iterations == level - 1:
                    orderedPositions += "4"
                    print("added 4")
                time.sleep(0.5)
                iterations += 1
                continue 
            elif pyautogui.pixel(1270, 425)[0] == 255: # pixel 5
                if iterations == level - 1:
                    orderedPositions += "5"
                    print("added 5")
                time.sleep(0.5)
                iterations += 1
                continue 
            elif pyautogui.pixel(1400, 425)[0] == 255: # pixel 6
                if iterations == level - 1:
                    orderedPositions += "6"
                    print("added 6")
                time.sleep(0.5)
                iterations += 1
                continue 
            elif pyautogui.pixel(1140, 550)[0] == 255: # pixel 7
                if iterations == level - 1:
                    orderedPositions += "7"
                    print("added 7")
                time.sleep(0.5)
                iterations += 1
                continue  
            elif pyautogui.pixel(1270, 550)[0] == 255: # pixel 8
                if iterations == level - 1:
                    orderedPositions += "8"
                    print("added 8")
                time.sleep(0.5)
                iterations += 1
                continue 
            elif pyautogui.pixel(1400, 550)[0] == 255: # pixel 9
                if iterations == level - 1:
                    orderedPositions += "9"
                    print("added 9")
                time.sleep(0.5)
                iterations += 1
                continue
        
        time.sleep(0.4)
        for position in orderedPositions:
            tempTuple = pixels.get(position)
            click(tempTuple[0], tempTuple[1])
            time.sleep(0.05)
        pyautogui.moveTo(1530, 425)
        level += 1
        iterations = 0



checkingLoop() # begin it all
```

also as a quick note im inexperienced with pyautogui so the problem could be obvious but for now I have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this as I don't have a Windows system handy, but I suspect that your program is getting out of sync with the program running on humanbenchmark.com.

When you learning the sequence of positions in the inner loop (`while iterations < level:`), if you find a match you use [time.sleep](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep) to sleep for 0.5 seconds. From the documentation for time.sleep:

> The suspension time may be longer than requested by an arbitrary amount, because of the scheduling of other activity in the system.

So in actual fact, the system is likely sleeping for *slightly longer* than 0.5 seconds each time.

In addition, the code inside your while loop takes a non-zero amount of time to run. So the time taken for each iteration will be 0.5 seconds, plus an arbitrary amount caused by other programs on your computer, plus the time taken for the code in your while loop to run.

After a certain number of iterations this might be enough to skip the final square turning white. You might detect the penultimate square turning white just before the final square turns white, and then because of the slightly longer delay, by the next time the loop runs the final square might already have started to turn dark. If this happens, the `while iterations < level:` loop will continue iterating indefinitely, as there will be nothing to trigger the value of the `iterations` variable to increase.

To make this more reliable you can use [time.perf_counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) to compare the time the sequence started and the current time. You can then use this to calculate the amount of time you should sleep such that each step in the sequence takes 0.5 seconds.

I tried implementing this in the code below. (This code is untested, so you might need to tweak a few things to make it work.) I also merged all of your if/elif blocks for white square detection into a for loop, added infinite loop detection to the inner while loop, and made the white square detection more robust by treating pixels with a red value of greater than 200 as "white", instead of a red value of exactly 255.

I also used a list to store the sequence instead of a string. In Python strings are immutable, so every time you add a new digit to the end of the string, internally Python will create a new string object. For example, if you have the sequence 1, 5, 3, 7, 8, then Python will create the strings "1", "15", "153", "1537", and "15378". Each time you make a new string, the old string will no longer be accessible and will eventually be garbage collected. It is probably more efficient to just use a list to start with to avoid the need for garbage collection. I don't think you need to worry about memory here; you would need to store a *lot* of steps before that becomes a problem.

```py
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import win32api, win32con

pixels = {
    1: (1140, 290),
    2: (1270, 290),
    3: (1400, 290),
    4: (1140, 425),
    5: (1270, 425),
    6: (1400, 425),
    7: (1140, 550),
    8: (1270, 550),
    9: (1400, 550),
}


def click(mouseX, mouseY):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((mouseX, mouseY))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0)


def checkingLoop():
    sequence = []
    level = 1
    step = 0
    iteration_time = 0.5
    max_iterations = 1000

    while True:
        i = 0
        while step < level:
            if i >= max_iterations:
                raise RuntimeError(f"Could not detect white square after {max_iteration} tries")
            for position, coords in pixels.items():
                # Check whether the square at this position is white.
                # If the red part of the pixel is greater than 200 we assume
                # that the square is either white or turning from white to dark.
                if pyautogui.pixel(*coords)[0] > 200:
                    if step == 0:
                        # We detected the first white square. Use the current
                        # value of the performance counter as the base time for
                        # detecting the other white squares in the sequence.
                        tick = time.perf_counter()
                    if step == level - 1:
                        sequence.append(position)
                        print(f"added {position}")

                    # Work out how much time we need to sleep given the base
                    # time we recorded and the number of steps so far in the
                    # sequence.
                    tock = time.perf_counter()
                    time_elapsed = tock - tick
                    delay = time_elapsed - (iteration_time * step)
                    sleep_duration = iteration_time - delay
                    time.sleep(sleep_duration)

                    step += 1
                    break
            else:
                # We didn't find any white squares. Sleep for a little time
                # before trying again to give other threads a chance to run.
                time.sleep(0.01)
            i += 1
        
        time.sleep(0.4)
        for position in sequence:
            coords = pixels.get(position)
            click(*coords)
            time.sleep(0.05)
        pyautogui.moveTo(1530, 425)
        level += 1
        step = 0


checkingLoop() # begin it all
```

Depending on how the sequence memory minigame is implemented, this too may fail after a certain number of steps. (Even if your program uses a timer to keep track of the length of each step, there is no guarantee that the minigame does the same.) To make your program even more robust, you would need to somehow monitor the minigame to work out when each step of the sequence starts and ends, without assuming that it takes a set amount of time.

Comment: hey Jack! thanks for taking time out of your day to respond to me I really appreciate it :). It turns out the problem is exactly what you suggested, the program was just getting out of sync with the human benchmark, and I just had to do some debugging to find out the best time to sleep the program for. And thanks for explaining how python stores strings I had no idea it worked like that and I will definitely keep that in mind for future projects. I converted the if statements to a for loop as well, so thanks for that suggestion too.

Comment: No problem. If this answer helped, please mark it as the accepted answer. :)